# Check a file is created on current month

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I have a file in directory, I have to check whether the file created on current month. I'm trying a solution in shell script.

Ex: my file path is `data/tmp/docs/test.txt`, I just wanted to check the file `test.txt` is created on the current month.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `date` or `busybox` `date`, the most common `date` implementations found on systems using Linux as their kernel:

```
if [ "$(date -r file +%Y%m)" = "$(date +%Y%m)" ]; then
  echo "file was last modified this month"
fi
```

(note that for symlinks, it looks at the mtime of the target).

POSIXly, the same could be achieved with:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C; unset -v IFS
  eval "$(date +'cur_month=%b cur_year=%Y')"
  ls -Lnd file | {
    read -r x x x x x month x year_or_time x &&
      case $month-$year_or_time in
        ("$cur_month-$cur_year" | "$cur_month"-*:*)
          echo "file was last modified this month"
      esac
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `find -ctime` and `date +%d`(number of day in current month) for that. Whole command would be like:

```
find data/tmp/docs/test.txt -ctime -`date +%d`
```

If file is newer, than that amount of days it will show output, if not, then output will be empty. So assign it to variable and check if it's empty

```
OUTPUT=$( find data/tmp/docs/test.txt -ctime -`date +%d` )
if [ -n "$OUTPUT" ] ; then echo "file created in current month" ; fi
```

Update:
As @StéphaneChazelas mentioned in comments, -ctime is not creation time, it's time of status change (f.e. chmod will update that date), but linux [stat structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) contains only:

```
time_t    st_atime   time of last access
time_t    st_mtime   time of last data modification
time_t    st_ctime   time of last status change
```

So IMHO ctime is the best choise, if there is no status changes on file after creation.

Comment: Note that `ctime` is the change-time, not creation time. (see Btime for the when the inode spawned into existence, mtime, for last modification time (creation time of the current content)).

Comment: That would also report  files that have been last changed on the last day of the previous month after the current time (and also files with times in the future, less likely)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for additional info. But unfortunately linux stat structure contains, Access Modify and Change dates, and no create date, so IMHO ctime is the best option for that.

Comment: That statx structure has btime, but GNU find at least doesn't support it yet. mtime at least can be seen as the creation time of the content (IMO, more relevant than btime in that regard), while `ctime` is neither the creation time of the content nor of the inode.

Comment: Unless the file is empty there *will* be a change on the file after creation. The ctime is also updated each time the file is written to.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. So only solutions are: write C code using syscall statx() or remount FS with noctime ? As the question wasn't about modification date.

Comment: There is no `noctime`, `ctime` is critical in the functioning of file systems. Again _creation time_ is ambiguous. In my experience, when people say creation time, say mean `mtime`, that is the time when the content was fully created. the birth time `btime` as returned by statx is generally not useful. So here, I'd use `-mtime`. See also GNU's `-daystart` option. You may also want to throw in a `-prune` and a `-L`.